# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Tags: python

I am attempting to insert data from a dictionary into a database. I want to iterate over the values and format them accordingly, depending on the data type. Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
def _db_inserts(dbinfo):
    try:
        rows = dbinfo['datarows']

        for row in rows:
            field_names = ",".join(["'{0}'".format(x) for x in row.keys()])
            value_list = row.values()

            for pos, value in enumerate(value_list):
                if isinstance(value, str):
                    value_list[pos] = "'{0}'".format(value)
                elif isinstance(value, datetime):
                    value_list[pos] = "'{0}'".format(value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

            values = ",".join(value_list)

            sql = "INSERT INTO table_foobar ({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(field_names, values)

    except Exception as e:
        print 'BARFED with msg:',e
```

When I run the algo using some sample data (see below), I get the error:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

An example of a value_list data which gives the above error is:

```
value_list = [377, -99999, -99999, 'f', -99999, -99999, -99999, 1108.0999999999999, 0, 'f', -99999, 0, 'f', -99999, 'f', -99999, 1108.0999999999999, -99999, 'f', -99999, 'f', -99999, 'f', 'f', 0, 1108.0999999999999, -99999, -99999, 'f', 'f', 'f', -99999, 'f', '1984-04-02', -99999, 'f', -99999, 'f', 1108.0999999999999]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: soulution for you: `values = ",".join(map(str, value_list))`

Answer (score 572, accepted):

`string.join` connects elements inside list of strings, not ints.

Use this generator expression instead :

```
values = ','.join(str(v) for v in value_list)
```

Comment: Can also use `.join(map(str, value_list))`

Answer (score 94):

Although the given list comprehension / generator expression answers are ok, I find this easier to read and understand:

```
values = ','.join(map(str, value_list))
```

Answer (score 24):

Replace

```
values = ",".join(value_list)
```

with

```
values = ','.join([str(i) for i in value_list])
```

OR

```
values = ','.join(str(value_list)[1:-1])
```

Comment: Another one  `values = ','.join(str(value_list)[1:-1])`

Comment: remove the `[`,`]` from your second example, a list comprehension is not required and by removing them you have a generator which is more efficient.

Comment: Actually, as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python , using a list instead of generator in the `str.join()` method is faster...

Answer (score 16):

The answers by [cval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923813/cval) and [Priyank Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887668/priyank-patel) work great. However, be aware that some values could be unicode strings and therefore may cause the `str` to throw a `UnicodeEncodeError` error. In that case, replace the function `str` by the function `unicode`.

For example, assume the string Libië (Dutch for Libya), represented in Python as the unicode string `u'Libi\xeb'`:

```
print str(u'Libi\xeb')
```

throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tomasz/Python/MA-CIW-Scriptie/RecreateTweets.py", line 21, in <module>
    print str(u'Libi\xeb')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xeb' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The following line, however, will not throw an error:

```
print unicode(u'Libi\xeb') # prints Libië
```

So, replace:

```
values = ','.join([str(i) for i in value_list])
```

by

```
values = ','.join([unicode(i) for i in value_list])
```

to be safe.

Comment: This is the best solution here! values = ','.join([unicode(i) for i in value_list]) that works in case you have a mix of integers and strings with extended ascii characters.

Comment: No longer an issue in Python3, `str('\xeb')` => `ë`

Answer (score 4):

String interpolation is a nice way to pass in a formatted string.

`values = ', '.join('$%s' % v for v in value_list)`

Answer (score 3):

you can convert the integer dataframe into string first and then do the operation e.g.

```
df3['nID']=df3['nID'].astype(str)
grp = df3.groupby('userID')['nID'].aggregate(lambda x: '->'.join(tuple(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

solution:

```
    email = ''.join([str(nip), settings.ORGANISATION_EMAIL_SUFFIX])
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements inside the list are not in the string format for this first we need to convert it to string then we can apply the join operation on that list as below :

```
summary = [ str(i) for i in summary ]
summery = " ".join(summary)
```