# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found?

Tags: python, join, range

```
print ('\n'.join([' '.join([i for i in range(1,j)]) for j in range(2,6)]))
```

Error

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

I went through the link [TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880813/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-int-found)  telling `string.join connects elements inside list of strings, not ints.`

I have updated my code like `print ('\n'.join([' '.join([str(i) for i in range(1,j)]) for j in range(2,6)]))`

I got the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Following code is working fine

```
print ('\n'.join([' '.join(['i' for i in range(1,j)]) for j in range(2,6)]))
```

My Out

```
i
i i
i i i
i i i i
```

Comment: `print ('\n'.join([' '.join([str(i) for i in range(1,j)]) for j in range(2,6)]))` works for me with no errors

Comment: `print ('\n'.join([' '.join([str(i) for i in range(1,j)]) for j in range(2,6)]))` doesn't give me any errors

Comment: @ChrisDoyle do `str = 'a string'` and try again

Comment: @Hippolippo Because you did not assign a string to `str` like OP has

Comment: @DeepSpace ah you think in some previous part of the code he has overwritten the str function by allocating an actual string to it?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle OP **did** assign something to `str`

Comment: Just don't assign variables to keywords ever and you will be fine

Comment: You can make your first line of code be `to_string = str` and then just call `to_string` instead of `str`