# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found i keep getting a type error in the last line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, typeerror, numeric

i keep getting a typeerror on this code specifically in the last line `.join(Q)`. can anyone help me with it?

```py
Q=[]
a = Question.split()
for i in a:
    if i in stop:
        continue
    else: 
        Q.append(1)
    b = " ".join(Q)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Also, in your code you reference a variable called `stop`. What is that?

Comment: And note that `join` can only join strings, not numbers.

Comment: `Q.append(1)` appends an integer. You can't use `str.join` on a list of ints. did you mean `Q.append("1")`?

Comment: 'code' stop = stopwords.words('english')
print(stop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880813/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-int-found)

Comment: Please edit the question with additional information instead of just a comment. And feel free to make a toy example. `stop = stopwords.words('english')` isn't something we can use. Instead pick a couple for the example, `stop = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. And add a `Question = ??` whatever it is. We should be able to copy your code, run it, and see the same result you see.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str) in [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
b = " ".join([str(x) for x in Q])
```

Answer (score 0):

`Q` contains integers and to be passed to `join()` it must contain strings. Use `Q.append("1")` to append strings to the list.