# Python3: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to print all of the possible character substitutions for the word "otaku".

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import itertools

user_input = "otaku"

dict = {
'c': ['c', 'C'],
'a': ['a', 'A', '@'],
't': ['t', 'T'],
'k': ['k', 'K'],
'u': ['u', 'U'],
'e': ['e', 'E', '3'],
'o': ['o', 'O', '0']
}

output = ""

for i in itertools.product(dict['o'],dict['t'],dict['a'],dict['k'],dict['u']):
    output += ''.join(i) + "\n"

print(output)
```

The above script works but I need the `itertools.product()` input (`dict['o'],dict['t'],dict['a'],dict['k'],dict['u']`) to be dynamic (e.g., `new_list`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import itertools

user_input = "otaku"

dict = {
'c': ['c', 'C'],
'a': ['a', 'A', '@'],
't': ['t', 'T'],
'k': ['k', 'K'],
'u': ['u', 'U'],
'e': ['e', 'E', '3'],
'o': ['o', 'O', '0']
}

new_list = []

for i in user_input:
    new_list.append(dict[i])

output = ""

for i in itertools.product(new_list):
    output += ''.join(i) + "\n"

print(output)
```

This errors with:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

I tried the solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880813/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-int-found), but converting the list to a str breaks the itertools.product line.

How can I pass dynamic input into `itertools.product()`?

Desired output:

```
otaku
otakU
otaKu
otaKU
otAku
otAkU
otAKu
otAKU
ot@ku
ot@kU
ot@Ku
ot@KU
oTaku
oTakU
oTaKu
oTaKU
oTAku
oTAkU
oTAKu
oTAKU
oT@ku
oT@kU
oT@Ku
oT@KU
Otaku
OtakU
OtaKu
OtaKU
Ot@KU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `for i in itertools.product(*new_list):`

you need to add a `*` to unpack the `new_list`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was the solution. Why is the wildcard needed there?

Comment: Your code is fine but when you pass `new_list` as an argument, you really are passing a list. What you want to pass are all the elements of the list. When you add an `*` you are unpacking the list and passing each element as a param. This is what is expected.

Comment: Look at this function: 
`def test_func(a, b, c):
   # do something`.

If I pass a list like `test_func(new_list)`, it will mean `test_func(a = new_list)`.
If I unpack the list like `test_func(*new_list)` it will mean `test_func(a=new_list[0], b = new_list[1]....)`.

Comment: Check this out. Really useful if you know how args and kwargs work: https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `*` to unpack it:

```py
for i in itertools.product(*new_list)
```

you can also do it by **list comprehension**

```py
c = ["".join(x) for x in itertools.product(*new_list)]
for i in c:
   print(i)
```