# Put multiple int in the where clause of sql

Tags: python, mysql

```
import pandas as pd

sql_query = '''
Select *
from datamart_table
where quantity in (%s)
'''
x = [10, 20, 30]
placeholders = ', '.join(i for i in x)  

SQL = sql_query%(placeholders)
df = pd.read_sql(SQL, connection)
```

Above is my snippet. I wish to fetch when the quantity is in list_x. Below is the error I am getting. I don't wish to convert values in x to string. Any way out.

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880813/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-int-found)

Comment: I think you are looking for a parameterized query.  I'm not too familiar with `pandas.read_sql()` but [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) says it takes a `params` option. So it would be something like: `sql_query = "select * from datamart_table where quantity in (%s, %s, %s)"` and then `df = pd.read_sql(SQL, connection, params = x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a string per the error:

```
placeholders = ', '.join(str(i) for i in x)
```

Full output:

```
sql_query = '''
Select *
from datamart_table
where quantity in (%s)
'''
x = [10, 20, 30]
placeholders = ', '.join(str(i) for i in x)  

SQL = sql_query%(placeholders)
print(SQL)
```

result:

```
Select *
from datamart_table
where quantity in (10, 20, 30)   # These are still ints
```

Comment: @Anant it's only a string insofar as it needs to be a string to be joined into a list of strings for the SQL query, which is ALREADY a string. See updated answer.